# Delete div generated by CakePHP Form create

Tags: cakephp

**CakePHP Code**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('KPI');?>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="..." action="...">
   <div style="display:none;">
       <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
   </div>
```

I want to delete auto generated div which display in html output. How can delete that div which generated by cakephp form create?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to jquery code to detect div in my forms but I don't need to unnecessary div.

Comment: @ndm Is it possible to do not generate hidden div?

Comment: That's not a very good reason, your selector should be specific enough to not match such id/class-less elements. Do you know what this markup is acutally good for? Because if you don't, then you really shouldn't remove it.

Comment: I have to use both `POST` and `Form Helper` then Can I remove that?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment (_Yes it is, by using GET or not using the form helper_) by accident.

Comment: I have large form data so I can't use `GET` method.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you should not remove that markup, besides that would only be possible by completely overwriting `FormHelper::create()`, see

- **[https://github.com/.../cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L426-L432](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L426-L432)**
- **[https://github.com/.../cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L462-L464](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L462-L464)**

Also note that there might be an additional hidden block at the end of the form, see `FormHelper::secure()`.

The only simpler way to remove the wrapper, would be to remove the hidden wrappers altogether, that would for example be possible by using a [**custom config**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#changing-the-tags-output-by-htmlhelper) for `HtmlHelper` where the `hiddenblock` tag is modified so that it doesn't contain the wrapper, however *that's not a good idea* - don't do it!

The problem here is that you can't just remove this specific wrapping `div` element, the hidden `input` and the `div` go hand in hand. And the `input` ensures that CakePHP is able to figure the proper request method (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`).

So instead simply make your jQuery selector more specific, do not just select `div` elements, instead make sure that your elements have a proper class set, and then select them by that `class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Kpi', array(
              'inputDefaults'=>array('div'=>'false', 'label'=>false)));
         ?>
```

Comment: Sorry! It's also generate div tag.

Comment: That simply won't work, there is no such option for `FormHelper::create()`.

Comment: Your new code also won't work, `inputDefaults` does not apply to these hidden elements. Also `false` shouldn't be in quotes. Anyways, there is no option that would affect the hidden div, just look at [**the source**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L462-L464)

Comment: just a minutes will try